# Access Attribute of Rails Test Fixture in Associated FixtureSet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, fixtures

## Background

My application defines a one-to-many relationship between Employee and Company models. I've assigned the Employee fixture a company using the label of the Company fixture (`37_signals`).  However, I also need to assign the `company_uuid`, which is generated by `SecureRandom.uuid`.

## Example

### app/models/

#### employee.rb

```
class Employee
  belongs_to :company
end
```

#### company.rb

```
class Company
  has_many :employees
end
```

### test/fixtures/

#### employees.yml

```
employee:
  name: dhh
  company: 37_signals 
  company_uuid: <%= "Access the 37_signals company fixture's uuid here!" %>
```

#### companies.yml

```
37_signals:
  name: $LABEL
  company_uuid: <%= SecureRandom.uuid %>
```

## Question

How can I access the attribute of a Fixture in another FixtureSet?

## Attempted

I've attempted to use the following lines as solutions:

```
company_uuid: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:37_signals).company_uuid %>
```

The above finds the company's primary key `id` value, then calls the `company_uuid` method, which is undefined for the integer. This is invalid.

```
company_uuid: <%= companies(:37_signals).company_uuid %>
```

The above finds reports `undefined method 'companies' for main:Object`

**Is there a conventional way to solve this problem?**

Comment: It turns out that this was an extraneous fixture.  To run with the example, you could say an Employee is created upon an internal JobAd being closed with an after_update callback.  Company has_many job_ads.  JobAd has_one Employee, and Employee belongs_to Company, Employee belong_to JobAd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, the first option should be to DRY out the data, so it only exists in one place. You could do this with a `delegate` so that `employee.company_uuid` will always be answered by `employee.company.company_uuid`.

If you really need it in the Employee model, the next best choice would be to use a callback (like `before_validate` or `after_save` depending on your use-case), that copies the value from the Company to the Employee object. You want to eliminate chances for the data value to diverge from what it's true source should be.

Finally, you could extract all the UUIDs into a hash accessible to both fixtures at the time of creation, and set both values like:

  `company_uuid: <%= UUIDs['37_signals'] %>`

...or similar

Comment: This isn't the immediate solution I'm looking for, but I do like all three options. Unfortunately, against my will, my app has widespread UUID syndrome, and I must keep that data.  Using callbacks is a feasible, but non-trivial, refactor considering my time-constraints (and lack of tests)!

Comment: After working on this further, I've seen the light!  Model callbacks were a relatively easy refactor.  With a little more test coverage and time spent refactoring, I think `delegate` will be an excellent solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best solution I've been able to devise:

```
company_uuid: <%= Company.find(ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:publish_and_export_album)).company_uuid %>
```

However, this solution does not seem *conventional*. <strike>Also, I believe that this succeeds with some luck since fixtures are loaded alphabetically.  If `Company` was named `Organization`, loading after `Employee`, then I think this would not work as intended.</strike> Actually, through trial and error I determined that this method works in the opposite direction, so the alpha-order has no detrimental effect.

Comment: Well, at the very least, please wrap that hideous construct within a well-named method! :P

Comment: if your doing your fixtures alphabetically (which rails sets by default) - this may not work for everyone. this will come up with an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if your setting a fixture which letter starts before your other fixture. and yah - a method would be nice :P

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue if you use [the fixture_builder gem](https://github.com/rdy/fixture_builder). It allows you to build a graph of model objects and give them fixture names, and saves them to .yml fixture files for you.

Comment: Looking at the number of downloads, I don't think I'd call that gem conventional. It's not a feasible refactor since this problem is widespread in my application. Thanks for the input!